# Ngrok can't connect to any port

Tags: linux, networking, ngrok

I'm getting the error dial tcp [::1]8080: connect: connection refused when I run ngrok and yes I tried other ports and I get the same thing.
I'm not sure why just cause I never had this problem before with ngrok  and I used ngrok for years.

I know ngrok isn't listening on any port I put in which is why I am getting this error message. The program just stopped working for whatever reason on anything. I want to fix this and know why after a long time having no issue with the program this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your code looks like but make sure the port is exposed. If it's exposed it should be working properly and giving you the redirect.

If you added/changed any firewall to your server for example in AWS make sure it's accepting the proper inbound IP address/ making it public.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if it was an issue with my firewall. If so I am not sure what. I checked and things seemed fine from what I know. But there could be something I missed. Let me know if you think there is something I should check and I will double check or check in case I haven't already. Well ngrok doesn't work on any pre-made program, my programs and even on it's own when I type ./ngrok http 8080 for example and I tried other port numbers as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568521/16505794 check this

Comment: I checked. I am getting the same issue